# Convert plural nouns into singular nouns

Tags: r, nlp

How can plural nouns be converted into singular nouns using R? I use the the tagPOS function which tags each text and then extract all of plural nouns which were tagged as "NNS". But what to do in case I want to convert those plural nouns into singular ones.?

---

```
library("openNLP")
library("tm")
acq_o <- "Gulf Applied Technologies Inc said it sold its subsidiaries engaged in pipelines and terminal operations for 12.2 mln dlrs. The company said the sale is subject to certain post closing adjustments, which it did not explain. Reuter."

acq = tm_map(Corpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(acq_o))), removePunctuation)
acqTag <- tagPOS(acq)
acqTagSplit = strsplit(acqTag," ")
qq = 0
tag = 0
for (i in 1:length(acqTagSplit[[1]])){
        qq[i] <-strsplit(acqTagSplit[[1]][i],'/')
        tag[i] = qq[i][[1]][2]
}

index = 0
k = 0
for (i in 1:(length(acqTagSplit[[1]]))) { 
    if (tag[i] == "NNS"){
        k = k +1             
        index[k] = i     
    } 
}
index
```

Comment: Thanks the comments of Aleksandar Dimitrov and tchrist. Maybe I must write my own rules for singularizing. Here is a useful online material for everyone who interests in the issue: An Algorithmic Approach to English Pluralization. If there are further answers, please guide me. Thanks

Comment: See also: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/pluralize

Comment: See also: https://github.com/trinker/qdap/blob/master/R/add_s.R (rudimentary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure you could pipe your data through an external program, or pre-process your data with it.

If you're doing tagging anyway, the German project [TreeTagger](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/corplex/TreeTagger/) does a nice job of tagging and lemmatising at the same time.

EDIT: tchrist was right to remind me that, whatever your purposes, if you're actually looking for the singular surface forms of your plural nouns, going for a home-baked solution isn't going to cut it at all.

And if you don't then Neo_Me (again, in the comments) seems to have found a package that does stemming in R: the package [snowball](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Snowball/index.html) (RStem seems to have been discontinued. AFAICT, Snowball replaces it.)

This is just an implementation or wrapper around the Porter stemmer, of course. Use at your own risk, it is going to stem stuff like *wives* into *wif* or something like that.

It just occurred to me, that R has [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/). Looking for "lemma" there made me aware of the Java-dependent package [wordnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordnet/index.html). It seems to have a `getLemma` function. The whole package is likely overkill for you, but might still get you somewhere if you can't find anything better.

Comment: English has quite literally thousands upon thousands of irregular plurals, and neither the Porter Stemmer nor Snowball does anything like a good job with them. They are especially lame with words with classical inflections like *bacterium/bacteria* and *criterion/criteria.* You have to write your own rules. Note that simply stripping an s from a simple word like *technologies* or *wolves* is wrong.

Comment: Best thing would be to use Stemmer in this case. `tm` `RStem` are the packages you should look into.

Comment: tchrist, you're right, and I didn't make it clear enough that "rolling your own" is going to be a bad idea. It might be a sufficient idea, if what you want is, say, a search engine. But it's linguistically inaccurate.

Comment: Neo_Me: I disagree with the stemmer suggestion, as it would suffer the same problems tchrist already mentioned: it's good enough if you don't need accurate results, but if you really *aim* for providing the exact singular form of a plural noun, stemmers are going to do an agonizingly bad job at it. Granted, I haven't yet looked at either tm or RStem (and am unlikely to do, since I don't use R for linguistics.)

Comment: Stemmers really aren't going to cut it. The OP needs a lemmatizer, like the one in WordNet or the one in the Stanford POS tagger.