# r substring string

Tags: r, string, gsub

```
gsub(".*s$", "", c("book", "books", "chair", "tables"), perl=T)
```

gsub(".*s$", "", c("book", "books", "chair", "tables"), perl=T)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just `s$` for the regex...?

Comment: You didn't understand me at all. Try `gsub("s$","",...)`.

Answer (score 2):

As Joran says in his comment, you are matching too much.  `.*s$` matches any string that ends with an `s`.  The entire string is matched, and thus the entire string is replaced with an empty string.

You want this:

```
gsub("s$", "", c("book", "books", "chair", "tables"))
```

Note that you don't need `perl=TRUE` for this expression.

Answer (score 0):

There could well be words that end in an "s" that are not plurals and you might not want to remove the last "s".  Here is another approach, using the tm package, but it stems "tables".

```
text <- c("book", "books", "chair", "tables", "glass", "mess")
library(tm)
text.stem <- stemDocument(text)
> text.stem
[1] "book"  "book"  "chair" "tabl"  "glass" "mess"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In your solution, tables -> tabl. But I need tables -> table. Any way to make plural words to singular?

Comment: It is very hard to do accurately (as demonstrated with table(s)..  Here is an SO question that informs far more than I can.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036902/convert-plural-nouns-into-singular-nouns